# Question about the necessity of the distributive property axiom used in the definition of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Pinter's *"A Book of Abstract Algebra"* defines a ring $A$ stipulating the following $3$ axioms:

1. $A$ with addition alone is an abelian group.
2. Multiplication is associative.
3. Multiplication is distributive over addition.

I am a little confused as to why the third axiom is needed. Doesn't axiom $1$ naturally lead to $3$? Consider the following example:

$(a \circ_+ b)^5 = (a\circ_+ b) \circ_+ (a\circ_+ b) \circ_+ (a\circ_+ b) \circ_+ (a\circ_+ b) \circ_+ (a\circ_+ b)$

Because the operation of addition is an abelian group, the above statement is equal to:

$a^5 \circ_+ b^5$

if we simply move the notation around...doesn't this read just like:

$5(a\circ_+ b)=5(a) \circ_+ 5(b)$ ...which could be generalized to any number.

From this explanation, it seems that multiplication's distributive property over addition is already *baked* into the system without the need to specify it.

What am I missing / incorrectly concluding? Cheers~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'll *(mostly)* write "$+$" and "$\times$" for the addition and multiplication, respectively, since I think it's ultimately clearer.

You're conflating exponentiation notation in the context with rings with exponentiation notation in the context of (non-abelian) groups: when we're working in a ring, "$a^n$" (for $a$ an element of the ring and $n\in\mathbb{N}$) denotes the *multplicative* expression $$a\times...\times a\quad\mbox{ ($n$ times)}.$$ In particular, we have $$(a+b)^5=(a+b)\times (a+b)\times (a+b)\times (a+b)\times (a+b)$$ *(and not "$(a+b)+(a+b)+(a+b)+(a+b)+(a+b)$" as in your post)*.

The point is that we have *two* different operations at play on the right hand side. Because of this, we can't really use the commutativity of "$+$" since we have to "get around" the multiplication $\times$ somehow.

> Note that this actually *does* match the notation used in the context of *abelian* groups: for $(G,*)$ an abelian group, "$a*...*a$" ($n$ times) is generally denoted by "$na$" rather than "$a^n$."

---

Note that **$(3)$ is the only axiom which tells you how $+$ and $\times$ relate**; in the absence of $(3)$, we would be able to just "glue together" an abelian group operation and an associative operation on a set to get a ring. For example, look at $\mathbb{Z}$ and - switching to unambiguous notation now - let both $\circ_+$ and $\circ_\times$ be the usual addition $+$. This is clearly not a ring, since it satisfies $(1\circ_+1)\circ_\times 1=3$ but $(1\circ_\times 1)\circ_+(1\circ_\times 1)=4$, but it satisfies axioms $(1)$ and $(2)$ from your list.

Comment: I was using the exponent notation to reflect how one thinks about "repeated composition" in groups.

Comment: @S.Cramer But the point is that you're using addition sometimes when you should be using multiplication: the right hand side of your expression shouldn't just use "$\circ_+$," regardless of how you want to notate it.

Comment: Hmmm. I may rewrite this question to get at the point I am trying to make (I think my notation is confusing to everyone). It seems, therefore, that the purpose of the distributive property is really to provide a rule for how multiplication interacts with addition.

Comment: @S.Cramer Serendipity - see the bottom of my edit!

Comment: great post! Just for clarification, then, step by step, the distributive property is really saying $x*(a+b) = (a+b) + (a+b) ... x \ times$ and, it just so happens, that because the additive operator is abelian, this simplifies to $x*a + x*b$. So, really, the distributive property is the rule  $x*(a+b) = (a+b) + (a+b) ... x\  times$. But because the additive operator is abelian, this can be rewritten into the form of $xa + xb$. 

Is that correct?

Comment: @S.Cramer No, that's not right. The "iterated addition" version of multiplication is **not** the ring operation: rather, it's a multiplication between a *natural number* and a ring element (just as in an abelian group). Distributivity governs how *ring addition* interacts with ring multiplication.

Comment: ohhhh, gotch ya. Because it would fail to correctly describe anything other than integers greater than zero. Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer Exactly. (Incidentally, if you've seen vector spaces already, there's an analogy between them, abelian groups, and rings. An abelian group is *(or rather, can be canonically thought of as)* a "vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$" (or more precisely, a $\mathbb{Z}$-*module* since $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't allow division). A ring is more complicated since it allows multiplication of "vectors;" the analogous fact is that a ring "is" a $\mathbb{Z}$-*algebra*.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in general, $a^5\neq a+a+a+a+a$. For example, consider the ring $\mathbb Z$  and let $a=1$.

Comment: I guess I am familiar with what exponents mean in the context of single operators. For example, in groups, $a^5$ would just mean $a \circ a \circ a \circ a \circ a$ I can edit the post to clarify.

Comment: My point is that $(a \circ_+ b)^5 = (a\circ_+ b) \circ(a\circ_+ b) \circ (a\circ_+ b) \circ (a\circ_+ b) \circ (a\circ_+ b)$ and not what you wrote in the post. I presume that $\circ_+$ is the addition and $\circ$ is the multiplication.

Comment: Ahhh, so the definition of exponents changes when we are dealing with two operators, such as in a ring.

Comment: @S.Cramer Actually, it's *already* changed in the switch from general groups to abelian groups - see my edit.